# Find continuous $f$ s.t. $f(x,y)^2 = x^2$ ($f: H \to \mathbb{R}$, H connected)

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

> (i) Show that a metric space M is connected if and only if every continuous integer-valued function on M is constant.
>
> (ii) Show that $H = \{(x, y) \in R^2 : x > 0\}$ is connected. By considering the function $f(x, y)/x$, or otherwise, show that there are precisely two continuous functions $f : H \to R$ such that $f(x,y)^2 = x^2$ for all $(x,y) \in H$.
>
> (iii) How many continuous functions $g : R^2 \to R$ are there such that $g(x, y)^2 = x^2$ for all $(x, y) \in R^2$?

I can do (i), and the connectedness of H.

My solution attempt for the rest: If $f(x,y)^2 = x^2$, then $f(x,y)/x = 1$ or $f(x,y)/x = -1$, i.e. $f(x,y) = x$ or $f(x,y) = -x$, which are precisely two continuous functions. Same answer for (iii).

This sounds wrong: it does not make use of any of the facts I proved before in the question (not even connnectedness of H!), and (ii) and (iii) seem setup to yield differing answers, not the same one.

Any ideas as to what I am missing? Hints especially appreciated.

Best wishes,

Leon

Comment: The problem is that the quotient $\frac{f(x,y)}{x}$ could be $1$ for some $x$'s and $-1$ for others. This is where your precedent work helps you.

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I didn't catch that. Thanks, that seems to be exactly it. This still yields the same answer to (ii) and (iii) though, right? (R^2 is connected) EDIT: Makes sense now I've seen your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint : The short answer to (iii) is "There are $2\times 2=4$ solutions."

Comment: Can you elaborate your answer in a little bit more detail?

Comment: @gen see my comment to the OP